# "that is one of the definitions of what Shakespeare-language does," that refers to？

Tags: grammar, reference

> At this very early and rather primitive stage, we could not give our student-subjects undiluted lines of Shakespeare because too much in the brain would light up in too many places: **that** is one of **the definitions of what Shakespeare-language does.** (From ACT)

I know "that" in bold refers to a definition of what Shakespeare-language does, but what is the definition because I cannot find it in the preceding sentence.

Comment: The phrase "Shakespeare-language" is poor English. A better version would be Shakespearean language.  If this is written by a teacher, I'm dismayed.

Comment: What is ACT? There are dozens of possible meanings - https://www.abbreviations.com/ACT

Comment: @ chasly - supports Monica Sry, It stands for American College Test, and I excerpt  this sentence from the Reading part.

Comment: Thanks. I'm British so I don't know about the American College Test!

Comment: The wider context can be read here https://11eggs.wordpress.com/2012/08/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an odd extract.

It implies that "there are many definitions of 'what Shakespeare-language does'"

And one of those definitions is "[make] (too) much in the brain light up in (too) many places".

The use of the the word "definition" is odd, since nothing is actually being defined.  Instead it is used to mean "part of the essestial facts about". Compare:

> Yes, control is important in tennis, because "hitting the ball over the net" is one of the definitions of tennis.

The overall meaning of the quote seems to be:

> We can't let young people read Shakespeare, because the language is essentially very stimulating.

However looking at the full extract it means

> We can't use lines of Shakespeare in our (simple and primitive) experiment on brain activity because they are too complex. (so we designed simple phrases that use one particular aspect of Shakespeare: using a word in an unusual grammatical context)

But, as I said, the quote is strange in both meaning and syntax.

Comment: Having found the full article, the reason for the oddity is that they are doing something odd: putting people into a brain scanner and monitoring brain activity as they read lines of text that include words being used with semantically meaningful, but grammatically odd ways.